# How to avoid this Syntax Error message: missing ; before statement?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

It works fine if I do:

```
 function GetImage(cell){
  if(cell=="1"){
    var html= "<img src='images/image1.gif'/>";
```

But it doesn't work if I try:

```
function GetImage(cell){
  if(cell =="1"){
    var html="<asp:Image runat='server' ImageUrl='images/image2.gif'/>";
```

On Firebug it shows:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
var html = "<img src="images/image2.gif" />";
```

Does this error occurs because I use asp:Image ?

Comment: you can't use javascript to dynamically build server controls.

Comment: You cannot add ASP.NET web controls like that on the client side.

Comment: Is there other way to add the controls?

Comment: add controls from server or add them but keep hidden and set display block when needed.